# If a and b are two sequences that converge to the same number, then f(a) and f(b) converge to the same number.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, functions, convergence-divergence

Entire Question:

Let $f:A\to \mathbb{R}$ be a unif. cont. function and $\underline{a},\underline{b}:\mathbb{N}\to A$ be two sequences which converge to the same number. Prove that $f(\underline{a}),f(\underline{b})$ converge to the same number.

My Attempt so far :

Say $\underline{a},\underline{b}\to \ell$. We know that $f(\underline{a})\to x$ and $f(\underline{b}) \to y$ for some $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$, since uniformly continuous functions preserve convergence. We will show that $x = y$. Let $\varepsilon > 0$, and we will argue that $|x-y| < \varepsilon$, for any $\varepsilon > 0$. We have, 
$$ |x-y| = |(x-f(a_n)) + (f(a_n) - f(b_n)) + (f(b_n) - y)| \leq |x-f(a_n)| + |f(a_n) - f(b_n)| + |f(b_n) - y| $$

What I want to do it to present an n large enough so that all three terms on the RHS of the inequality are less than $\frac{1}{3}\epsilon$.

Any guidence is appreciated !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $d$ be the metric on $A$ with respect to which $f$ is uniformly continuous.
Let $\epsilon>0$. Since $f$ is uniformly continuous, there is $\delta>0$ such that if $d(z,w)<\delta$, then $|f(z)-f(w)|<\epsilon/3$. There is $N$ such that if $n>N$ then 
$$d(a_n, l)<\delta/2$$
and 
$$d(b_n, l) <\delta/2$$,
since you know there are $N_1$ and $N_2$ such that the statements hold, and if you take the maximum of these two you find $N$. Now, by the triangle inequality
$$d(a_n, b_n)\leq d(a_n, l)+d(b_n, l)<\delta.$$
Moreover, there exists $M$ such that if $n>M$ then 
$$|x-f(a_n)|<\epsilon/3$$
and 
$$|y-f(b_n)|<\epsilon/3,$$
since we find $M$ again by taking appropriate maxima. Now if $n>\max \{M, N \}$, then 
$$|x-y|<\epsilon.$$

Answer (score 0):

You should also consider splitting $|f(a_n)-f(b_n)|$ like this:
$$|f(a_n)-f(b_n)|\le|f(a_n)-f(\ell)|+|f(\ell)-f(b_n)|$$
and of course, bound each term with $\epsilon/4$ instead of $\epsilon/3$.